# Transform "for" loop into a mean in Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave, mean

So i have this, it's practically a "manual" way of doing a mean

```
function DESV=cada(arch,col);
a=load(arch);
primera=a(:,col);

n=length(primera);
M=zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n-4
    for r=i:i+4
    M(i)=M(i)+primera(r);
    end
end
M=M/5;
M
```

Fancy thing it does is that it calculates it every 5 steps (i subtracted 4 to the loop because the archive doesn't have exactly a multiple of 5 as length)
Now the teacher told me i have to put a mean in there instead of calculating it as a sum.
I have no idea how to do that, I've tried but i get different results, i know how to use mean but i don't know how to make it calculate every 5 steps, what would be the structure of the loop.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like it's just a moving average filter. Maybe googling that can help you out?

Comment: "i subtracted 4 to the loop because the archive doesn't have exactly a multiple of 5 as length" <- That is not the reason to subtract 4. It is because your moving segment of 4 elements would otherwise exceed the list. Did you write that code? Do you understand it?

Comment: Yes it just rang a bell of what you did.

Comment: Also yes i googled and it said i have to use tsmovavg when i searched moving average, i don't think that's what the exercise wants me to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
function DESV=cada(arch,col);
a=load(arch);
primera=a(:,col);

n=length(primera);
M=zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    M(i)=mean(primera(i:max(i+4,n)));
end

DESV=M
```

Comment: No explaination due to time reason. Feel free to edit and enhance this answer 404.